# Bash indirect array addressing?

Tags: arrays, bash

Suppose I have some `bash` arrays:

```
A1=(apple trees)
A2=(building blocks)
A3=(color television)
```

And index `J=2`, how to get the array contents of `A2`?

Comment: This is very cool. I consider myself a bash expert and I was always under the assumption that bash cannot do array indirection such as `${!ind[@]}` but I never thought to introduce a temp var to solve it.

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer. You will be able to accept it when the time limit expires. Here is an example of the usual way that arrays are used with indirection: `d=13; e=24; f=35; a=(d e f); echo ${!a[1]}` which results in "24".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've already found a resolution, this can be done by:

```
$ Aref=A$J
$ echo ${!Aref}
building
$ Aref=A$J[1]
$ echo ${!Aref}
blocks
$ Aref=A$J[@]
$ echo "${!Aref}"
building blocks
```

Comment: How can you assign to, say, `A$J`? You need a name without expansion to assign to, but `A$J=(...)` doesn't work.

Comment: that's the letter "A" followed by the contents of the variable "J". If J == 2, then you could see it as A + ${J} == A2

Comment: @musiphil, `printf -v "A$J" '%s' "value to assign"` will do the trick. See [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thanks for the pointer. `printf -v` works only for a single value, not for arrays, and `read -a` can split a string into arrays but is subject to the delimiter and the word separator, and cannot write to an associative array. `declare` seems to be the most versatile: `declare "A$J=hello"`, `declare -a "A$J=(hello world)"`, `declare -A "A$J=([x]=hello [y]=world)"`.

Comment: @musiphil, `printf -v` certainly does work to assign to array elements with bash 4.4, but you're right that that doesn't go back in time as far as I'd like.

Comment: ...on 4.4, `declare -a arr; printf -v arr[1] '%s' hello; printf -v arr[2] '%s' world; declare -p arr` emits as output `declare -a arr=([1]="hello" [2]="world")`

Comment: @musiphil, ...back on 3.2.57, `read` appears to still do the trick: `read -r 'arr[1]' <<<'hello'; declare -p arr` behaves as-intended.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yes, assigning to a single array element seems to be the same as assigning to a scalar variable. (But just make sure you quote the array element reference as "`arr[1]`", because that may expand to `arr1` if there's a file named `arr1`. :))

Answer (score 21):

It’s worth to note, that even an index will be substituted at time the variable is evaluated:

```
$ A2=(building blocks)
$ Aref=A2[index]
$ index=1
$ echo "${!Aref}"
blocks
```

Comment: **FANTASTIC.** years of shell scripting + reading the manual at least a dozen times + *explicit attempts at exactly this* failed to surface this little gem! note, like literal indexes, **any arithmetic expression is valid, including nested expansions**, eg. `cycle=(0 1 2); ref='cycle[i++%${#cycle[*]}]'; echo ${!ref} ${!ref} ${!ref} ${!ref} ${!ref} ${!ref} # => 0 1 2 0 1 2`

Comment: I wonder if this is a feature explicitly intended to be so, or if we are exploiting side-effect of the indirect expansion, which could silently disappear from future releases.

Comment: @davide Still works! :-) I don't think this will change. Shell code is all about phases of macro-like literal expansion into words, and the man page has this to say: _... the first character of parameter is an exclamation point ... introduces a level of indirection ... this variable is expanded ... **used in the rest of the substitution** ... known as indirect expansion_. AFAICT, it's 100% inline with expectations.

Answer (score 5):

Today (with bash 4.3 and later), the best practice is to use [nameref](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare#nameref) support:

```
A1=(apple trees)
A2=(building blocks)
A3=(color television)
J=2

declare -n A="A$J"
printf '%q\n' "${A[@]}"
```

...will properly emit:

```
building
blocks
```

This is also available as `nameref A="A$J"` on ksh93. See [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2Freference_variables) for details.