# Properly Specify an Array and Element through Variables in a Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, variables, zsh

Consider the following nonsense array:

```
# KIND[ID]=NAME
MONKEYS[1]="Oo Oo"
MONKEYS[2]="Aa Aa"
MONKEYS[3]="Ba Nana"
LIONS[5]="Mister Mufasa"
LIONS[7]="Cocoa Puff"
LIONS[8]="Lala Leo"
TIGERS[13]="Ben Gal"
TIGERS[15]="Tee Eye Double Guh Err"
TIGERS[22]="Oh Esex Diez Punto Cuatro"
```

With a given `KIND` and `ID`, I'm attempting to build a string that resembles `$NAME[$ID]` to get the associated name.

When explicitly stating an array name, the command behaves as expected `echo "${LIONS[5]}"=>"Mister Mufasa"`).  However, whenever a variable is used, the shell responds with the given character in the string.

```
$LIONS[5] => 'e' # The fifth letter in "Mister Mufasa"
```

In other cases, I can't find a way to control interpolation to get the `NAME`

```
KIND="LIONS"
ID="5"

# Attempt to return value of `LIONS` when `KIND=LIONS`
echo $"${KIND}"; echo "\$${KIND}" #=> "$LIONS"
echo "$${KIND}" #=> "57800{KIND}" Interpolates "$$"
echo "\$\${KIND}"; "\$\${KIND}" #=> "$${KIND}"
```

I found the following works albeit "ugly"...

```
eval echo `echo \\$${KIND}`
```

However when introducing the `ID` things break once again:

```
eval echo `echo \\$${KIND}[$ID]`
#> title:5: no matches found: $LIONS[5]
#> no matches found: $LIONS[5]
```

I feel like I'm missing something *very* simple. I have a hunch I'm forgetting to escape something, but I'm not quite sure what.

Also, what "less redundant" alternatives to `` eval echo `echo... `` or `` eval echo `print... `` exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash indirect array addressing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582137/bash-indirect-array-addressing)

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006). You should probably use Bash 4 and its associative arrays or another language with more powerful data structures.

Comment: @l0b0 I actually am employing a more portable indirect reference above since using "`\$$var`, ... preceded by an eval (and sometimes an echo)" is the classic [indirect reference](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html). The syntax that Gordon introduced below `${!VAR}` seems to be Bash specific.  @Dennis, the FAQ utilizes the same method as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, use indirect addressing:

```
REF="$KIND[$ID]" # Sets REF to "LIONS[5]"
echo "${!REF}"   # Prints "Mister Mufasa"
```

EDIT: In zsh, use nested expansion instead:

```
echo "${(P)${KIND}[ID]}"
```

Comment: Perfect for Bash, but not much else. The latest ZSH performs an expansion to `echo "${REF="$KIND[$ID]"}"` which throws back an 's' once again.

Comment: I gave up on finding something  universal. It seems expansions are handled very differently across shells.

Comment: Yes, portability tends to be difficult (/impossible) for anything outside the POSIX standard.  And since neither arrays nor indirect expansion are in the standard...