# Can I use a variable name to indirectly select an array to write to?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to populate several files in bash. I have code that performs the logic that I want, but right now, making it run over more files means copying-and-pasting. How can I do this repeatably, in a way that scales as the number of files increases?

```
# first iteration: read from shuffle1.txt, write to initialpos1 and finalpos1
i=0;
while read -r a b; do
    i=$(( $i + 1 ));
    initialpos1[$i]=$a;
    finalpos1[$i]=$b;
done < shuffle1.txt

# second iteration: read from shuffle2.txt, write to initialpos2 and finalpos2
i=0;
while read -r a b; do
    i=$(( $i + 1 ));
    initialpos2[$i]=$a;
    finalpos2[$i]=$b;
done < shuffle2.txt

# third iteration: read from shuffle3.txt, write to initialpos3 and finalpos3
i=0;
while read -r a b; do
    i=$(( $i + 1 ));
    initialpos3[$i]=$a;
    finalpos3[$i]=$b;
done < shuffle3.txt
```

Comment: Maybe you could add samples of  `shuffle.txt` and an example of the result/output expected.

Comment: BTW, re: "new to the forums" -- Stack Overflow is very explicitly a Q&A site; we don't intend or try to be a forum -- whereas in a forum, people are there to help you individually, in a Q&A site, we're here to build new entries for a knowledgebase; the intended consumer is people who read it later, over time; not just the initial poster, so the goal is to have a question and answer that are clear, readable and accessible to as many people as possible, vs stopping at satisfying the person who asked.

Comment: *Reading* from an array indirectly is already covered in our knowledgebase at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582137/bash-indirect-array-addressing; I'm working on finding a duplicate that covers indirectly writing. BTW, both of these topics are covered in [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encapsulate this code, consider a function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[0-3].*|4.[0-3].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4.4+ is required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

# usage: read_columns_to_array arrayname1 arrayname2 filename
read_columns_to_array() {
  local a b
  declare -g -a "$1=( )" "$2=( )"
  local -n __array1=$1 __array2=$2
  while read -r a b; do
    __array1+=( "$a" ); __array2+=( "$b" )
  done <"$3"
}

for ((i=1; i<=3; i++)); do
  read_columns_to_array "initialpos${i}" "finalpos${i}" "shuffle${i}.txt"
  declare -p "initialpos$i" "finalpos$i" # print the arrays' current content to demonstrate
done
```

- The `$BASH_VERSION` check ensures that we throw an error message when running a version of bash too old to support the necessary features -- most particularly *namevars*, which we later access with `local -n`.
- `funcname() { ...; }` is the POSIX-standardized way to declare functions in shell languages. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete comparing it to some other, less-portable approaches.
- `local` prevents our variables from leaving the scope of the function in which they're defined; unless this is done, variables are global by default. `local -n` is more special, creating a *namevar* -- a shell variable that acts as an alias to a different variable name. Here, we use `__array1` and `__array2` as the alias names, to avoid any likelihood of conflict with actual names we may be passed on invocation.
- `declare -g` declares a *global* variable, even when run inside a function; `-a` makes that variable an array. Thus, our use of `declare -g -a` defines an array that outlives the end of the function in which it's defined.
- `array+=( "first new value" "second new value" )` is modern syntax for appending to an existing array, which unlike the `array[$index]=value` form, doesn't require the caller to maintain a counter themselves.

Note above that we're using `"$i"` to substitute in a numeric value -- right now, that's in a range from 1 to 3, but it could just as easily be 1 to 50.